# Neokree Navigation drawer: Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to Set up a Navigation Drawer by Neokree https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer on **Android Studio** with no success.

After adding this to my gradle -> build.gradle file

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialNavigationDrawer:1.3.3'
}
```

And then i get this Error Saying "Gradle project Sync Failed" and this below

Error:(27, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'

Possible causes: The project 'MaterialNavigationDrawer' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.

Gradle settings The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.

Apply Gradle plugin.

This is my gradle folder -> Build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialNavigationDrawer:1.3.3'
}
```

I know am doing something wrong for sure, and I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Instead of using a third party library for navigation drawer you can use androids own navigation drawer provided in its design library for reference   check this link http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: Thanks for the advise, androids own navigation drawer is actually better.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great library called [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer). You can integrate this library in less than 5 minutes in your project (read its README.md and Wiki - a lot of informations is available there!).

Good luck!

Comment: +1, Thanks for your answer, but I found Androids own navigation drawer tutorial here https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer which was a good help.

Comment: You're welcome @HtmlTosin ! The link's content above is nice! Thank you too!